# Objective-C Where to define initial Class Properties

Tags: objective-c, class, properties

just wanted to ask where I define initial class properties?

From other languages I am used to define some standard properties in the head before the content of the class starts.

For example paths to files. Settings and so on.

Where I fill these initial properties with values in Objective-C?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure you want "properties"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public property needs to be define in .h file.

```
@interface MyClass {
}
@property(nonatomic, reatin) NSString *a;//Define as per needs, then synthesise in .m file

@end
```

For private property you need define inline category in .m file-

```
@interface MyClass ()

@property(nonatomic, reatin) NSString *b;//Define as per needs, then synthesise in .m file
@end

@implementation MyClass

@synthesize a = _a;
@synthesize b = _b;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
//You can initialise property here or in init method

self.a = @"Demo1";
self.b = @"Demo2";
}

//Now you can have other code for this class.
@end
```

Comment: they don't have to be public. Also can I define the value there as well?

Comment: hmmm... this looks to me more like defining setters and getters... I want to create initial properties with already defined values and they should be private.

Comment: typically that would be a constant with a setting value

Comment: @mogio - i was just updating this, you can check this, how you can initialise these.

Comment: so values can't be predefined in objective-c? they get their values delivered by functions, right?

Comment: Yes, if you are using property then in some of the method you have to set initialise that.

Comment: one more thing you can do if you want to predefine some value. don't define property, define a instance variable with some initial value, like in .m file - under implementation section you have a line code like 0 int i =5; and then you can access this value throughout the class.

Comment: so you aren't declaring the (public / private) type by using a statement. - It's more the place where they are produced that decides if they are public or static, right?

Comment: @mogio: "Properties" precisely means "getters and setters". If you want something else, you are using the wrong terminology

Answer (score 2):

Generally it's something like:

MyClass.h:

```
extern NSString * const staticValue1;
extern NSString * const staticValue2;

@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    NSString *_strval;
    int _intval;
    float _fltval;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *strval;
@property (assign, nonatomic, readwrite) int intval;
@property (assign, nonatomic, readwrite) float fltval;

@end
```

MyClass.m:

```
NSString * const staticValue1 = @"Something";
NSString * const staticValue2 = @"Something else";

@interface MyClass

@synthesize strval = _strval;
@synthesize intval = _intval;
@synthesize fltval = _fltval;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        [self setStrval:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is a %@", @"string"]];
        [self setIntval:10];
        [self setFltval:123.45f];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self setStrval:nil];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

This demonstrates the use of synthesized properties which are being used here to manage the memory of the instance variable `_strval`, which requires retaining/releasing to avoid memory leaks.  Note that `[self setStrval]` is initialised with an autoreleased object (from `[NSString stringWithFormat`) and will be retained by the setter method.  Alternatively these methods can be called using the following syntax, if you prefer:

```
self.strval = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is a %@", @"string"];
self.intval = 10;
self.fltval = 123.45f;
```

Comment: So that means that even good old VO's (Value Objects) which sometimes are just used to share predefined values must get a init call to make values accessible

Comment: @mogio: Depends, if it's a value known at compile time, then you could simply use a literal (for example `@"My String"`).

Comment: can you be more specific with that. Where would I create that value? in the head file?

Comment: @mogio: I have updated my answer with one possible implementation.

Comment: great.. that was exactly what I was looking for. So the values would exist before any function is called. And also they are accessible within the object by other functions by being private as well... right? I just then don't understand why we use the statement "extern" as that would be the opposite. Isnt't it?

Comment: NSString *staticValue1 = @"Something"; in the m file doesn't seem to be valid. Xcode's runtime compiler doesn't like it

Comment: @mogio It should have `const` in it, as per the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some of what you are after can be implemented with class methods.

Class methods are coded with a `+` (instead of the instance methods' `-`), and can't refer to instance variables, as they are not associated with any specific instance of the class.

This is a class method to return a default string:

```
+ (NSString *)myDefaultString
{
    return @"Some default value";
}
```

You call it by simply calling it with the class name at the receiver's place. Imagine you have defined the method in a class called `MyClass`, the you call it like this:

```
NSString *str = [MyClass myDefaultString];
```

You'll notice that there is no `alloc`/`init` calls in this.

Comment: Thanks Monolo. There are a lot of ways. I just realize that it would be better to just program in a different way, instead of trying to port other ways of programming to objective-c. I like the way constants and properties exist in the head of a class as it provides a good overview about settings constants etc.  I do that normally in Java, PHP or AS3.  I have to stop thinking in other languages and just be more objective-c :)